# Retrieve Bloomberg Historical Data - API

Tags: matlab, api, bloomberg

From the below code, I was attempting to retrieve `250` observations rather than `177`. The gap is due to the fact that the `call` only considers `trading days` which is fine to me.

```
 s='SX5E INDEX';
 f='LAST_PRICE'
 t= datestr(today()-250,'mm/dd/yy');
 T= datestr(today(),'mm/dd/yy');
 [dt,~]=history(con,s,f,t,T)
```

However, is there a way of retrieving the last 250 observations from `today()`, whatever the starting date `t` is ?

Best

**EDIT**

@Daniel : Based on your suggestion, and Going forward with `while loop`, I've ended up with the below `way around` which is free from any `Matlab` default `calendar` setting. **Thanks**

```
while l~=p
n=p-l;
t=t-n;
[dt,~]=history(con,s,f,t,T);
l=length(dt);
end
```

Comment: Is the financial toolbox available? Then you could use [`isbusday`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/isbusday.html)

Comment: Are you really talking about [tag:jbloomberg]? Looks like you are using the MATLAB function.

Comment: I don't know matlab but you may be able to specify an earlier date (say 2 years ago) and specify a number of points - otherwise you need to adjust the start date...

Comment: @Daniel: `isbusday` has confirmed that the ` api call` skips lots of non-business days, matching my expectation. But the question focus more on the way to query 250  historical data observations from `T`.

Comment: @Daniel: `jbloomberg`, is a spelling mistake and it has been removed

Comment: @assylias: ok for the intuition... will keep searching. However, adjusting `start date` might not be optimal. Suppose you have 100 different data each day and need to build `matrices`, you might need to debug code each time (costly) you face `dimension issue`. Before I was importing Bloomberg data to `sql` then using `select top 250` as a way around...

Comment: @dark.vador The Excel API has a `points` override where you can specify the number of points - I don't know if it's available in the matlab API.

Comment: @assylias: good to know on `Excel api` side. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my idea to use `isbusday` wasn't well explained in the comments. Here is what I would try:

```
n=250;
m=n;
while(sum(isbusday(today()-n:today()))<m)
    missing=m-sum(isbusday(today()-n:today()));
    n=n+missing;
end
```

Count the number of missing days, add the missing days and check again (in case you added a holiday)

You should end up with n the total number of days you have to query.

(Lacking the toolbox, I was unable to test the code)

Comment: the idea is quite `smart`, ending up with `n=362`. However, used as input in my query `length(dt)=255` and not `250`, fyi. My little concern about the suggested way-round is  `calendar days`. Which calendar is taken into account for `holidays`? Assuming I have 2 distinct data from different geographical areas (hence different `holiday calendar`) the result (`n`) might be misleading, still triggering `dimension issue` as described to @assylias. isn't it?

Comment: to illustrate my point please do `isbusday(today()-10:today)`, then you will see the `15-feb-2016` is considered as `non-business day` as by default this function considers `US calendar`, not European (taking into account there is not a uniform European holiday calendar). currently looking for ways to add specific `calendar` within this function, otherwise `n` might be wrong. Best,